# Count lines of code for each user on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools

Is there any way to find out how many lines of code each user from Visual Studio Team Services has written? Just like GITHUB does?
(example : 60 commits / 61,834 ++ / 3,943 -- )

If this can't be done on Visual Studio Team Services, is there any way to do it on Visual Studio/TFS Power Tools or any other tools?

Comment: What do you want the information for? There may be another way to get it?

Comment: basically I want to know how much each developer contributed on each branch of development

Comment: Many years later, but number of lines code written does not equal to productivity. 

A good developer will write a one-liner to solve some issue instead of a 5-line block of code. By measuring productivity with lines written, any junior dev could outdo a senior developer, which isn't a realistic way to look at productivity at all.

What if a junior developer introduces 10 lines of code to solve a problem, and then, his code causes bugs. Then he would have to write even more lines of code to fix the bugs. Meanwhile the senior developer only wrote a few lines, and didn't have to fix the mess

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Team Services does not yet have that capability. If you are using TFS, you get access to that info through an Analysis Services Cube that is part of the reporting integration.

On Team Services, you should be able to connect your own instance of Sonar Cube to get that information. You would have to run your own Sonar server which you can probably do in Azure.

Comment: Ok, Im not familiar with Analysis Services, im gonna try and keep you informed

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps y TFS 2018 U2 offers a rest api for GIT and others aspects.

Details: [Git Rest Api for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)